# Swift iOS UITabBar Customization

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uitabbar

I have a tab bar. I changed its colour, gave it a corner radius, set its border width and colour, and everything is working good. Until now, everything is done in a storyboard.

Now I want to give it left and right margins, as by default it is sticking to the screen's edges.

This is the tab bar's current look:

[image]

The black arrows point to the lines that stick to the screen's edges. I want space between this line and the edges.

Comment: margin.. can you share the screenshots, that exactly you want.

Comment: I want some space between black line and wall of screen from left and right of tabbar. I don't have that screen shot.
let me know if you didn't understand.

Comment: @Myaaoonn please have a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create this placeholder view inside a custom `UITabBar` as below,

```
class CustomTabBar: UITabBar {

    let roundedView = UIView(frame: .zero)

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        roundedView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        roundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 12.0
        roundedView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        roundedView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        roundedView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.addSubview(roundedView)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let margin: CGFloat = 12.0
        let position = CGPoint(x: margin, y: 0)
        let size = CGSize(width: self.frame.width - margin * 2, height: self.frame.height)
        roundedView.frame = CGRect(origin: position, size: size)
    }
}
```

Set this class for TabBar in `storyboard/xib`. It should give you the following,

[image]

Comment: Perfect!
Thanks alot

Comment: @HafizShoaibAwan Glad it helped!

Comment: @Kamran How do you think, is it possible to move tab bar higher?

Comment: It solved the problem, but now pressing on tab not working, I am stuck at home tab, can you help me out?

Comment: okay problem solved,
just need to add this line in "awakeFromNib()" method
roundedView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

Comment: @Said-AbdullaAtkaev Actually it is possible to move the `tabBar` higher but it is not recommended as it will leave black space at the bottom. It will be better to increase the `height` of the `tabBar` and move the `roundedView` and `tabBar titles` up.

Comment: @Kamran How can I move tab bar higher in animation? For example for 20 px higher

Comment: In `CustomTabBarController`, override `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and set the `newFrame` for `tabBar`. New frame will have the same `x`, `width` and `height` but custom `y`(e.g, `tabBar.frame.origin.y - 20`) that you want to change.